TypeORM Error when using camel case alias in addSelect
I'm using TypeORM and Postgresql .I have 2 entities event and eventParticipant relationship is one-to-many. I want to sort by the number of eventParticipants with booking status so I used addSelect with subQuery but the error QueryFailedError: column "bookingparticipantsortable" does not exist occurred. I could solve it by changing the alias writing from camelCase to snake_key as follows bookingParticipantSortable -> booking_participant_sortable and everything worked fine.
This is my code:
  async templeGetEvents(userData: IUserData, args: TempleGetEventArgs) {
    const { tid: templeId } = userData;
    const { ended, take, skip, orderBy } = args;
    const queryBuilder = this.eventRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('event')
      .where('event.isDeleted = :isDeleted', { isDeleted: false })
      .andWhere('event.templeId = :templeId', { templeId: templeId[0] })
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'event.eventParticipantTypes',
        'eventParticipantTypes',
        'eventParticipantTypes.isDeleted = false',
      )
      .loadRelationCountAndMap(
        'eventParticipants.currentParticipant',
        'event.eventParticipants',
        'currentParticipant',
        (qb) =>
          qb.where(
            'currentParticipant.isDeleted = false AND currentParticipant.bookingStatus = :approveStatus',
            { approveStatus: EBookingStatus.APPROVED },
          ),
      )
      .loadRelationCountAndMap(
        'eventParticipants.bookingParticipant',
        'event.eventParticipants',
        'bookingParticipant',
        (qb) =>
          qb.andWhere(
            'bookingParticipant.isDeleted = false AND bookingParticipant.bookingStatus = :bookingStatus',
            { bookingStatus: EBookingStatus.BOOKING },
          ),
      )
      .skip(skip)
      .take(take);

    if (ended) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere('event.endDateEvent < :now', {
        now: new Date(),
      });
      queryBuilder.addOrderBy('event.endDateEvent', 'ASC');
    }

    if (orderBy && orderBy.bookingParticipant) {
      queryBuilder
        .addSelect((subQuery) => {
          return subQuery
            .select(
              'COUNT(eventParticipantCount.id)',
              'bookingParticipantSortable',
            )
            .from(EventParticipant, 'eventParticipantCount')
            .where(
              "eventParticipantCount.event = event.id AND eventParticipantCount.bookingStatus = 'BOOKING' AND eventParticipantCount.isDeleted = false",
            );
        }, 'bookingParticipantSortable')
        .orderBy('bookingParticipantSortable', orderBy.bookingParticipant);
    }

    const [events, count] = await queryBuilder.getManyAndCount();

    return returnPagingData(events, count, args);
  }

Why doesn't it work when I use bookingParticipantSortable as an alias? Is there a way for me to use bookingParticipantSortable as an alias and still have everything work fine?

Don’t use CamelCase, only snake_case. Or use double quotes “ everywhere around your database object names. And accept all the bugs when you forget them. Just don’t use uppercase
